# Positioning element in the middle of dynamically sized element

Tags: css, position, centering

I have to put "Play" icon and text "Play" in the center of  element that contains  and its height and width depend of that image - they are changing depending of the user's screen.
I was trying to use it like this

```
a.thumbnail:hover:after
{
    content: "Play";
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

But actually the top left corner of the :before element is in the middle and looks displaced... can you suggest me better solution?

Comment: you can use display: table > display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to the code

```
  margin: -10px -25px; /** height/2 width/2 **/
```

or use translate the same way

```css
 div{
   position: relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
   margin: 20px auto
 }
div:after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 20px;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   background: green;
   transform: translate( -50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div><div/>
```

Comment: Great :) I love simple solutions but what If the size of the :after container is dynamical ?

Comment: then you will need JS since `var` is not yet done in css  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables  and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables       You can try SASS or LESS

Comment: yes, the element centered dynamical, but if you changes width and height on 100px you can add margin -50px and height: -50px (-(width/2) and -(height/2))

Comment: Can’t you use `calc()` as well?

Comment: @T1000 if the container is dynamic the you can use transform see the example above.

Comment: @Tambo that `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` line is genious.